# Efficient structure for two directional search

Tags: python, search, optimization, structure, bigdata

I have 5 objects: Session, Query, Result, Action, POI. 
So, after loading values, I created a separate list of objects(sessions_list, queries_lis,...). 
Then, I should relate these lists as follow: 
every session has a list of queries, 
each query has a list of results, 
each result probably has a list of actions,
and each action can have a POI. 
Approximately I have 400K sessions, 700K queries, and so on. 
Afterwards, I need to search in both directions; for example actions that belong to a session or sessions that have this action,....
How can I define my structure, regarding size of my data and type of iterations?

```
class Session:

    def __init__(self, session_id, duration_seconds, device_name, start_time):
        self.session_id = session_id
        self.duration_seconds = duration_seconds
        self.device_name = device_name
        self.start_time_utc = start_time
        self.queries = []
        self.result_ids = []
        self.action_ids = []

class Query:
    def __init__(self, search_id, action_date, query_id, language, lat, longitude, total_results, query, country, country_subdivision, start_results, session_id):

        self.search_id = search_id
        self.action_date = action_date
        self.query_id = query_id
        self.results = []
        self.action_ids = []
        self.language = language
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.total_results = total_results
        self.query = query
        self.country = country
        self.country_subdivision = country_subdivision
        self.start_results = start_results
        self.session_id = session_id

class Result:
    def __init__(self, result_id, place_id, search_id, rank_of_result):
        self.result_id = result_id
        self.place_id = place_id
        self.search_id = search_id
        self.query_id = []
        self.rank_of_result = rank_of_result
        self.actions = []
        self.session_ids = []


class Action:
    def __init__(self, action_id, date, act_type, place_name, query_id, rank_of_result, place_id, session_id):
        self.action_id = action_id
        self.action_date_utc = date
        self.action_type = act_type
        self.place_name = place_name
        self.query_id = query_id
        self.rank_of_result = rank_of_result
        self.place_id = place_id
        self.session_id = session_id
        self.search_ids = []
        self.results_ids = []
        self.pois = []


class POI:
    def __init__(self, place_id, latitude, longitude, name, country):
        self.place_id = place_id
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, you should post more about what you've tried so far and ask specific questions about that.

Comment: @robbrit: I tried following structure:

Comment: '
class Session:
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        # attributes
        self.queries = []

class Query:
    def __init__(self,attributes):
        s# attributes
        self.results = []

class Result:
    def __init__(self, attributes):
      # attributes
        self.actions = []
        self.session_ids = []

class Action:   
    def __init__(self, attributes):
        # attributes
        self.pois = []
class POI:
   # attributes'

Comment: Post it in your question, not in a comment. Make sure it formats correctly so that people can read it.